# Notepad++ replace last octet (?) from IP adresses with a 0

Tags: notepad++, regex

Sorry guys for a very simple question, but I couldn't find the correct way to replace the last octet (is this the correct word for it) with a "0".

So far I tried several things, after searching these forums, but or it replaces 1 number (not 1, 2 or 3 numbers after the last dot).

Here are 3 examples:

```
1.1.1.1
22.22.22.22
333.333.333.333
```

In all these cases the last (.1, .22 or .333) need to replaced with a 0.
Reason for this is I want to put these annoying IP's who try to access SSH in a block list permantly.

So far all solutions I found don't give a correct result. Maybe someone has a working regex for Notepad++ to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I want to put these annoying IP's who try to access SSH in a block list permantly* i think you make a mistake. Most part of Internet nodes have a mask which differs from /24. You may block excess addresses. Including addresses which may not be blocked - for example, public or commercial proxies, or eved datacenters which hosts such nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much more efficient without capture groups:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+$`
- Replace with: `0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d+         # 1 or more digits
$           # end of line
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Applicable if each line contais IP address only. But, given that this is a list of IP-addresses, it's a smart decision.

Comment: Nice clean and detailed solution. This solution is nicer imho therefor accepting this one as answer. TY!

Answer (score 5):

```
Find: ((\d{1,3}.){3})\d{1,3}
Replace: \10
```

Comment: Thank you! I will bookmark this for future usage!

Comment: @Joanne [NPP help - Regular expressions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) is more suitable bookmark.